# How to Display data model content in cell for row at indexpath?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, didselectrowatindexpath

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkmG6.png)https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRZu5.png
Hi I'm trying to display the name and the pointsWorth of a specific object in a tableview. But the xcode answers missionTitleLabel cannot be used on missionCell. Is it possible to display information from the object that I've created?

Thankful for any help I can get!

Here is my code:
MasterViewController.swift:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MissionCell", for: indexPath)
    let event = self.fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)
    self.configureCell(cell, withEvent: event)

    let mission = missions[indexPath.row]
    MissionCell.missionTitleLabel?.text = mission

    return cell   
}
```

example Data Model:

enum CategoryEnum {
    case a
    case b
    case c
    case d
}
    public class Mission {

```
var name: String
var pointsWorth: Int
var colorTheme: UIColor
var description: String
var category: CategoryEnum

init(name: String, pointsWorth: Int, colorTheme: UIColor, description: String, category: CategoryEnum) {
    self.name = name
    self.pointsWorth = pointsWorth
    self.colorTheme = colorTheme
    self.description = description
    self.category = category
}
```

}         let mission1 = Mission(name: "a", pointsWorth: 50, colorTheme: .blue, description: "a is the fist letter in the alphabet", category:.a)

let mission2 = Mission(name: "b", pointsWorth: 60, colorTheme: .red, description: "b is the second letter in the alphabet", category:.b)

var missions: [Mission] = [mission1, mission2]

MissionCell.swift:

```
import UIKit
```

class MissionCell: UITableViewCell {

```
@IBOutlet weak var missionTitleLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var missionPointLabel: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

}
```

}

Comment: What's the type of `mission`? is it a string?

Comment: Yes    It is a String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you should use `cell` variable as `MissionCell`.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MissionCell", for: indexPath) as! MissionCell
   let event = self.fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)
   self.configureCell(cell, withEvent: event)

   let mission = missions[indexPath.row]
   cell.missionTitleLabel?.text = mission.name

   return cell   
}
```

Hope it help.

Comment: Thanks! your code removed the error but the name is not being displayed in the tableview when I run the app.

Comment: Can you debug in `override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell `?
Did the code trigger in here?

Comment: Hey, can you check your storyboard ? You should link `delegate` and `datasource` to your viewcontroller like this http://i1380.photobucket.com/albums/ah191/amar_11s/Amarendrasingh/coonectdelegate_zpsi8fublta.png

Comment: It seems like my delegate and datasource is linked to my view controller      [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkmG6.png

Comment: When I set up breakpoints I can see that the following methods doesn't run: 

Prepare for segue
Cell for row at indexpath
configureView
+ the dataModel: Datamodel.swift

Comment: How about your MasterViewController class ? Can you update full code for this class?

Comment: I solved it!! it was because I referred to object instead of my data in the cell for row at index path Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

You should assign the values like this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MissionCell", for: indexPath) as! MissionCell
    let event = self.fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)
    self.configureCell(cell, withEvent: event)

    let mission = missions[indexPath.row]
    cell.missionTitleLabel?.text = mission.name


    return cell   
}
```

Keep in mind that using the force cast to MissionCell is only when you know for sure that there's one kind of cell type, otherwise you will crash.
Consider:

```
if let cell = cell as? MissionCell {
  cell.missionTitleLabel?.text = mission.name

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! After doing this I get the following message: cannot assign value of type Mission to type String?  Is there some way I can access the objects name property?

Comment: You should use `mission.name`

Comment: Thanks orxelm! This removed the error but the name is not being displayed in the tableview when I run the app.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot? do you see the right number of cells, but they are just empty?
Maybe you didn't connect the labels to the cell labels?

Comment: something must have gone wrong because the second time i ran the app i received a sigbart        reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier MissionCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

Comment: Go to your storyboard, select the custom cell inside your table view, open the utility inspector (right side) and set the cell identifier to `MissionCell`

Comment: Perfect that removed the sigbart   I provided a screenshot with the tableview above

Comment: It seems like the table view doesn't display the right number of cells

Comment: Probably you are not using the datasource methods right. I would refer to a beginner guide for UITableView usage in iOS.

Comment: I have looked at several guides for UITableView but it seems  
like the following methods doesn't run: Prepare for segue, Cell for row at index path, configureView  + the dataModel: Datamodel.swift

Comment: How do you initialize your UIViewController?

Comment: I solved it!!  it was because I referred to object instead of my data in the cell for row at index path    Thanks for all your help your are a Legend!